# Xpath exclude attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

My task is to find all the actors who were born in the USA, but not in California. I do belive i'm supposed to use [Not(@BirthPlace = 'California')] but it won't work

so far, this is the right path
 //Disney/Actors/Actor[contains(./BirthPlace, 'USA')]

but what do i have to do, to not include California

```
<Actor id="GwynethPaltrow">
<Name>Gwyneth Paltrow</Name>
<BirthDay>1969-03-11</BirthDay>
<BirthPlace>Los Angeles, California, USA</BirthPlace>
</Actor>
 <Actor id="ChrisEvans">
 <Name>Chris Evans</Name>
 <BirthDay>1981-06-13</BirthDay>
 <BirthPlace>Boston, Massachusetts, USA</BirthPlace>
 </Actor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
/Actors/Actor[contains(./BirthPlace,'USA')][not(contains(./BirthPlace,'California'))]
```

As an aside - there have been LOTS of Actors-related questions recently on SO. If it's not a secret - is that some school project or something?

Comment: So when i tried alone it didnt work, i typed the same thing now and it worked. seems like ur a magician or something :)